# C++ Passing a derived class as a base class template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having trouble passing a class `DerivedObject` (part of class `DerivedClass` derived from template class `BaseClass`) derived from `BaseObject` (part of template class `BaseClass`) as a template argument to template class `BaseClass`.

This way, both Base and Derived classes have the access to the object pool, that can contain derived objects. This sounds a bit confusing, so here is the example:

```
template <class TDerivedClass, class TDerivedObject>
class BaseClass
{
protected:
    class BaseObject
    {
        // Class implementation
    }
    void foo() 
    { 
        static_cast<TDerivedClass*>(this)->foo(); 
    }
    std::vector<TDerivedObject*> m_objectPool;
};
```

The above is the base class implementation.

```
error C2065: 'DerivedObject' undeclared identifier
```

The above error is cause by the first line of the class definition bellow:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<DerivedClass, DerivedClass::DerivedObject>
{
protected:
    class DerivedObject : public BaseObject
    {
        // Class implementation
    }
    void foo()
    {
        // Method implementation
    }
};
```

Is there a way to do this? If not, is there a better solution that would give me the same / similar functionality?

Comment: I do not know if this will help, but you may want the CRTP (see link below). For the compilation error, you may need a forward declaration of class DerivedClass. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @ErikAlapää, I don't think it's even possible to forward declare the *subobject* `DerivedClass::DerivedObject` - and it can't be done before declaring the inheritance for `BaseClass`.

Comment: I think you could have a `std::vector<void*>` and wrap `m_objectPool` in one or more accessors functions that cast the elements as `TDerivedClass::DerivedObject*`.  I don't have a new enough compiler handy to test exact syntax (so this is a comment, not an answer).

Comment: @JSF why `std::vector<void*>` when you have a perfectly good and sane alternative: `std::vector<BaseObject*>`?

Comment: @NikBougalis Yes, that would be one way around it, although I would like to avoid any casts (which would be needed in _DerivedClass_ to cast the _BaseObject_ to _DerivedObject_). Thank you, I'll keep this in mind as an alternative

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: You are correct, you cannot forward-declare the nested class. So he may have to un-nest the definition of DerivedObject.

Comment: @ErikAlapää How would I go about un-nesting the definition of _DerivedObject_? By declaring the _BaseObject_ outside of the _BaseClass_?

Comment: @PaulA, it may be sufficient to declare the nested class BaseObject as public, and then un-nestDerived object. A few quick experiments with your compiler should help. Adding an answer with some example code in case that helps.

Comment: This is related to CRTP, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859050/using-inner-class-with-crtp, and short answer is that you can't do it with inner class DerivedObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing something similar to what was requested:

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

template <class TDerivedClass, class TDerivedObject>
class BaseClass
{
public:
    class BaseObject
    {
        // Class implementation                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    };

protected:
    // void foo()                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    // {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    //     static_cast<TDerivedClass*>(this)->foo();                                                                                                                                                                                         
    // }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    // std::vector<TDerivedObject*> m_objectPool;                                                                                                                                                                                            
};

class DerivedClass;
class DerivedObject : public BaseClass<DerivedClass, DerivedObject>::BaseObject
{
    // Class implementation                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<DerivedClass, DerivedObject>
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        // Method implementation                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution worked best, giving me the same functionality I intended in the question.

Comment: @PaulA. Nice to be able to help. C++ is a complex language, but it is a really nice tool to have. And the more I learn, the more I like it. I also try to stay away from too complicated uses that only C++ gurus could decipher. Next book for me to read is Scott Meyer's new Effective C++ book, adapted/re-written for C++11.

Answer (score 5):

At this point

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<DerivedClass, DerivedClass::DerivedObject>
```

The compiler has not seen `DerivedClass::DerivedObject` so you get an undeclared identifier error.  As they type has not been seen you cannot use it as a template parameter.  You don't get one for `DerivedClass` as you already have declared `DerivedClass` as a `class`.

You could change you base class and have it store a `std::vector<BaseObject*>` in it and if you do that then you can change your code to:

```
template <class TDerivedClass>
class BaseClass
{
protected:
    class BaseObject
    {
        // Class implementation
    };
    void foo() 
    { 
        static_cast<TDerivedClass*>(this)->foo(); 
    }
    std::vector<BaseObject*> m_objectPool;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<DerivedClass>
{
protected:
    class DerivedObject : public BaseObject
    {
        // Class implementation
    };
    void foo()
    {
        // Method implementation
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I thought about doing that, but I would like to avoid any casts (which would be needed in _DerivedClass_ to cast the _BaseObject_ to _DerivedObject_ to have the derived functionality). That is why I asked the question, to find out if there are any other ways. However, I will keep in mind your implementation if any other alternative is absent.

Comment: "DerivedClass to cast the BaseObject to DerivedObject to have the derived functionality)." Perhaps use virtual functions instead of casts.

Comment: @n.m. I do not want to couple the _BaseObject_ to the functionality of _DerivedObject_, as the former meant to be a general-purpose class (i.e. many different, completely uncoupled implementations of _DerivedObjects_ are needed in my case). So the only way would be to use casts.

Comment: You already assume `TDerivedClass` derives from `BaseClass` (as evidenced by the cast), and you already assume `TDerivedClass` should have a function named `foo` with a certain signature (as evidenced by the call). By introducing a virtual function, you do not widen these assumptions. Moreover, it looks like you can simplify your code considerably, as `BaseClass` doesn't really need to be a template any more.

Answer (score 1):

From your example code, I get the impression that you want to provide different implementations for different base classes. Is there any special reason for using templates? If not, you could use classic polymorphism instead:

```cpp
class BaseClass
{
  class BaseObject {};
  virtual ~BaseClass() {} // <- do not forget to provide virtual dtor!
  virtual void foo() = 0;
  std::vector<BaseObject*> m_objectPool;
};
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
  class DerivedObject : public BaseObject {/*...*/};
  virtual void foo(){/*...*/}
};
```

Again, BaseObject would offer virtual or pure virtual functions - as you need.

One thing, however, you lose this way: the guarantee that in the vector there are always the objects of one specific BaseObject sub-type. If this matters for you, you could protect the pool and only allow to add new BaseObjects via DerivedClass. If this is not applicable, I might think up another solution from within BaseClass.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You can think of _BaseClass_ as a general-purpose class (like a general object pool for example). The derived functionality of _BaseObject_ will differ greatly between each class, hence I cannot put all the derived methods as virtual ones in _BaseObject_. The _DerivedClass_ needs to access the _DerivedObject_ functionality in the pool, while _BaseClass_ needs access of minimal _BaseObject_ functionality from the pool (for example for book-keeping, etc). I use templates for better performance as this might be performance-critical code.

Comment: "I cannot put all the derived methods as virtual ones in BaseObject". You shouldn't need that. If `BaseObject` doesn't know about them, great; omit them.  If `BaseObject` uses some of them (like it uses `foo`), *you have already put that information in `BaseClass`, in a much less usable form*.

Comment: Well, I see what you mean... This can be solved easily, IF you are under complete control which objects can get into the pool - i. e. that the derived class assures that only derived objects can get into the pool. THEN you simply can cast: static_cast<DerivedObject*>(m_objectPool[0])->bar();

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind having the DerivedObject structure separately from the DerivedClass you may do something like that:

```
template <class T>                                                                                                                                           
struct ObjectTypeTrait                                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                            
   static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "undefined trait");                                                                                                                      
};

template <class TDerivedClass>                                                                                                                               
class BaseClass                                                                                                                                              
{                                                                                                                                                            
protected:                                                                                                                                                   
class BaseObject                                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                                        
  // Class implementation                                                                                                                                
};                                                                                                                                                       

void foo()                                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                                          
   static_cast<TDerivedClass*>(this)->foo();                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                                          
std::vector<typename ObjectTypeTrait<TDerivedClass>::obj*> m_objectPool;                                                                                   
};

class DerivedClass;                                                                                                                                          

class DerivedObject                                                                                                                                        
{                                                                                                                                                          
   // Class implementation                                                                                                                                  
};                                                                                                                                                         


template<>                                                                                                                                                   
struct  ObjectTypeTrait<DerivedClass>                                                                                                                        
{                                                                                                                                                           
   using obj = DerivedObject;                                                                                                                                
};                                                                                                                                                          


class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<DerivedClass>                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                            
protected:                                                                                                                                                   


    void foo()                                                                                                                                                 
    {                                                                                                                                                          
      // Method implementation                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                          
 };
```

I do not claim this to be very brilliant solution, but you can get the idea - using type traits or typedefs

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution seems a bit confusing to me, as I am fairly new to _templates_. I'm not familiar with type traits, so I will try to find more information about them, and perhaps keep this implementation in mind as an alternative.