# Can't use CRTP for inner class

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I'm trying to use CRTP for common functionality of several iterators types. As stated here
[Using inner class with CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859050/using-inner-class-with-crtp) it's impossible to use CRTP for inner class, so I move the base iterator class out of the container class and inherit it inside the container for the iterator. But I still got

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class ConcreteIteratorBase<Node<int>, std::iterator_traits<Node<int>*>, std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, Node<int>, long int, Node<int>*, Node<int>&> >'
```

error.

Here is the minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class NotEqFromEqMixin : public T
{
public:
  bool operator!=(T const & other) const
  {
    return !(static_cast<T const &>(*this) == other);
  }
};

template <typename Iterator, typename Traits, typename StdBase>
class IteratorHelperMixin : public NotEqFromEqMixin<Iterator>, public StdBase
{
public:
  using pointer = typename Traits::pointer;
  using reference = typename Traits::reference;

  pointer operator->()
  {
    return &**this;
  }
};

template <typename NodeT, typename TraitsT, typename StdBaseT>
class ConcreteIteratorBase
  : public IteratorHelperMixin<ConcreteIteratorBase<NodeT, TraitsT, StdBaseT>, TraitsT, StdBaseT>
{
public:
  using Super = IteratorHelperMixin<ConcreteIteratorBase<NodeT, TraitsT, StdBaseT>, TraitsT, StdBaseT>;
  using typename Super::pointer;
  using typename Super::reference;

  ConcreteIteratorBase(pointer node) : node(node) {}

  reference operator*() noexcept { return *node; }

  bool operator==(ConcreteIteratorBase const & other) const noexcept { return node == other.node; }

protected:
  pointer node;
};

template <typename Value>
class Node
{
public:
    ~Node() { delete next; }


    Node* next = nullptr;
    Value value;
};

template <typename Value>
class List
{
public:
    using NodeType = Node<Value>;

    void push(Value value)
    {
        NodeType* newNode = new NodeType();
        newNode->value = value;
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }

    class iterator :
        public ConcreteIteratorBase<
            Node<Value>,
            std::iterator_traits<Node<Value>*>,
            std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, Node<Value>>
        >
    {
        using Super = ConcreteIteratorBase<
            Node<Value>,
            std::iterator_traits<Node<Value>*>,
            std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, Node<Value>>
        >;
        
        public:
        iterator(NodeType* ptr = nullptr) : Super(ptr){}

        iterator& operator++()
        {
            if (this->node)
            {
                this->node = this->node->next;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        Value& operator*()
        {
            return this->node->value;
        }

        bool operator==(const iterator& other) const
        {
            return this->node == other.node;
        }
    };

    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator{head};
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator{};
    }

    NodeType* head = nullptr;
};


int main(int , char**)
{
    List<int> list;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        list.push(i);
    }

    for(auto & val : list)
    {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"Here is the minimal reproducible example:"*, Reproducible, yes, minimal, no. that [version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b55d6a27192346de) is already simplified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you misuse CRTP as you do a circular inheritance:

`ConcreteIteratorBase`
-> `IteratorHelperMixin<ConcreteIteratorBase, ..>` -> `NotEqFromEqMixin<ConcreteIteratorBase>`
-> `ConcreteIteratorBase`

You should drop the inheritance here

```
template <typename T>
class NotEqFromEqMixin //: public T
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
public:
  bool operator!=(T const & other) const
  {
    return !(static_cast<T const &>(*this) == other);
  }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4400bca7a7002dd)